# Issue Testing my iPhone App on My Personal Device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I have just built my first app in Xcode 4.3.2. I want to test it on my iPhone which is currently running iOS 6.0.  The Organizer window in Xcode tells me this is a mis-match situation. I have read through a lot of the comments on here regarding this type of error message but it seems that the only solution is to run my app on Xcode 4.5. Is this really the only way I can test the app on my iPhone? As I said, I am brand new to iOS and Xcode and I am a bit hesitant to gamble with opening my app in the new version. Can anyone help!? Thanks.

Comment: Upgrading Xcode to 4.5 should be perfectly safe. You'll need to do it if you want to try your app on your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need Xcode 4.5 to run your app on any device running iOS 6.0.  Xcode is highly backwards compatible with projects created using old versions of Xcode.  Upgrading is your only option, and doing so shouldn't cause any issues.